# Magento2: Not showing Meta title & description on category page

Tags: magento-2.2.5, meta-tags, meta-title, meta-description, meta-keywords

I'm having issues with the website's meta information. If I set the default meta information, it will display the same information tag for all the pages.

But when I'm trying to set the meta info for a specific page then the Meta title and description do not display.

I have set the Meta description & title for one category. In this case, the Meta description & title tag showing for the same category page.

**Solution I applied to display both the tags for category pages:**

I have created one observer & set the description for the current category. But when I tried to set the title then I got the below error.

> Recoverable Error: Object of class Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title
> could not be converted to string in
> /var/www/html/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php
> on line 125

I used the below code to set the meta title & description.

> $this->_pageConfig->setMetadata('title', 'some meta title');
>
> $this->_pageConfig->setDescription($desc);
>
> $this->_pageConfig->setKeywords($keyWrds);

Thanks for any help.

Comment: check this https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/11368

Comment: I have checked it but it's also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to set Metatitle,

`$this->_pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Your Title'));`

Comment: Hi @aravind, I have checked the same. It's also not working. It will not add the meta tag.

Comment: hello @DeepakKumar could you see the description and keywords set?

Comment: The keywords showing by default. But the description also was not showing so I have added the meta description through observer. So now the description is showing but the title not.

Comment: could you show me the updated code of setting the title.

Comment: I have set the title by using the above shared functions by me & the function shared by you. But nothing working for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Refer block and its method,

> \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View::_prepareLayout()

In this way you can set the meta title and Description,

```
$category = $this->getCurrentCategory();
if ($category) {
    $title = $category->getMetaTitle();
    if ($title) {
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set($title);
    }
    $description = $category->getMetaDescription();
    if ($description) {
        $this->pageConfig->setDescription($description);
    }
    $keywords = $category->getMetaKeywords();
    if ($keywords) {
        $this->pageConfig->setKeywords($keywords);
    }
    if ($this->_categoryHelper->canUseCanonicalTag()) {
        $this->pageConfig->addRemotePageAsset(
            $category->getUrl(),
            'canonical',
            ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'canonical']]
        );
    } 

}
```

Comment: Hi @oscprofessionals it will update the meta title into the page title. But my concern is with the meta title tag that not showing to the category & product page.